# Can't get value from asyncstorage in react native to be intial state

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I am looking for a way to write my code so that I can set my `Redux toolkit` state to be coming from the `asyncstorage`. Here is my code:

```
const initialState={
token: null,
session: AsyncStorage.getItem('sessionId') || null,
loading: false,
error: false
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
name: 'user',
initialState,

  reducers:{
   ......
   }
})
export default  userSlice.reducer;
```

Definitely, `AsyncStorage` returns a `Promise` so it is not getting resolved before I assigned the value to `initial state`. How Do I achieve this? In web, this can be done. How do I access the `AsyncStorage` as the first place to check if the user has a `sessionId`?

Comment: What's stopping you from using `await`?

Comment: But initialState variable is not an async function. It is an object.

Comment: @kingsJayson Two options 1) wait until you have the sessionId *before* you create the redux store or 2) Make getting the sessionId from async storage an async action via createAsyncThunk (for example).

Comment: The second option looks promising, how can I implement it? Or even the first option. Any sample to guide me?

Comment: Option 1): there is a createStore() or configureStore() call somewhere in your code. You can run other code before this function is called. Option 2): check the official docs for redux-toolkit's  createAsyncThunk, there are some examples. Anything that returns a promise should work out of the box.

Comment: I have tried to see where and how to run the getItem code inside this part of my code and I can't get it to work. export const Store = configureStore({
   
    reducer: {
        cart: cartReducer,
        user: userSlice,
    },
 
})